# Is the following sentence correct?

Tags: conjunctions

> It indicated *that* eating food varied significantly with animal size, *whereas* drinking water did not varied significantly with animal size.

Is adding two conjunctions (that and whereas) in one sentence correct?

Comment: Welcome to ELL. We are glad you asked a question, but it doesn't seem that you read our [**tour**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [**Help Center**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages first. We don't proofread here. Please **[edit]** your question to tell us what usage you don't understand. If you don't, your question may be closed, and we would rather help you!

Comment: Let's give the new poster a couple of hours to add context before voting to close.

Comment: My question is adding two conjunctions (that and whereas) in one sentence is correct?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with "that" and "whereas".  However, the second "varied" should be "did not vary".  You could actually simplify the sentence by leaving off the redundant portion; just end with "did not".  It would be understood to parallel the earlier portion.

Comment: @user178049 It is now at least an understandable question about a specific grammatical matter. What is _that_ here? It does not appear to be a conjunction. Why not have a go at an answer?

Comment: @fixer1234 Is _that_ really a conjunction here? Seems to me that you could write a useful answer. I'm way too hammered to write one myself.

Comment: @user178049 It's some kind of a sooper-sekrit coordinating modificationalizer of quantificalization. Only BillJ can explain this form, and only to himself.

Comment: @P.E.Dant, yeah, you don't want to attempt an answer when you're hammered.  :-)  OK, I got the ball started.  Feel free to tweak it if you have any ideas.

Comment: @P.E.Dant of course it's a conjunction. It's a subordinating conjunction (or subordinator according to H&P) introducing the sub clause.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a native speaker and I learned something from you, so thanks.

> It indicated **that** eating food varied significantly with animal size, **whereas** drinking water did not varied significantly with animal size.

You're correct that both "that" and "whereas" are conjunctions.  "Whereas" joins together clauses.  "That" introduces a clause (see [M-W: that -- conjunction](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/that)). However, there's nothing wrong with "that" and "whereas" in the example, they are both used appropriately.

The second "varied" is incorrect, though.  With **do** or **did**, the present tense, **vary**, is required:

> It indicated that eating food varied significantly with animal size, whereas drinking water **did not vary** significantly with animal size.

You could actually simplify the sentence.  When you make a direct comparison like this, where one case is just the negation of the other, you don't need to repeat the redundant portion.  The second case is understood to parallel the first.  You could end the sentence with "did not":

> It indicated that eating food varied significantly with animal size, whereas drinking water did not.

Comment: @user178049, I didn't read M-W far enough.  You're right.  It actually is a conjunction--it's used to introduce a clause.  I'll correct the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's a subordinating conjunction. Btw it's worth pointing out that the "that" is optional in this case.

Comment: @user178049, thanks for the fix.  This is a bit out of my area.  If I understand subordinating conjunction, it joins a dependent clause to a main clause.  In the example, the first phrase is the main clause.  I'm confident that it's a conjunction, but not really qualified to define it beyond that.  :-)  In terms of "that" being optional, I think that is technically true, but the sentence is complex.  Leaving it out seems to read much less smoothly.

Comment: Yup, "It indicated that eating food varied significantly with animal size" is the main clause and "eating food varied significantly with animal size" is the subordinate clause. It's confusing because this terminology is outdated. In modern grammar, "that" here is just a meaningless subordinator that do nothing but introduce the subordinate clause. Btw, I'm not a qualified person either. I'm just a wannabe linguist here. :)